# how to download project when learn to use react router

Tags: node.js, git

I want to follow its' tutorial, but I don't know the thing what it's talking about.
[image]

First, it says I need `git clone` sth.
Where should I enter `git clone https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial` to? Does it mean that I should open my webstorm where npm is:

[image]

and then open `Terminal` and enter it into the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have Git downloaded - go [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads) if you haven't already downloaded it.

Open a terminal in the folder where you want to work (I don't recommend the npm folder, use something like My Documents, or whatever your Operating System's equivalent is).

Then type in the instructions line by line. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can either run those commands in the terminal or integrate it with your IDE:
[Using Git integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-git-integration.html)